# Intellij junit how to

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I have moved from eclipse to intellij.

In eclipse, I had two packages:

- src/code
- src/tests

Now i have created an intellij project and copied one of my old eclipse project's src/ into the intellij src/ folder.

In eclipse, if I wanted to add Junit so I did:

```
Build Path -> Add External Jars -> Junit -> Finish
```

How to do this in intellij??

Becaue i get the following errors for my junit tests

```
Error:(3, 24) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(3, 1) java: static import only from classes and interfaces
Error:(4, 24) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(4, 1) java: static import only from classes and interfaces
Error:(5, 24) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(5, 1) java: static import only from classes and interfaces
Error:(6, 24) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(6, 1) java: static import only from classes and interfaces
Error:(10, 17) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(11, 17) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(12, 25) java: package org.junit.runners does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Method 1:

If you know where the Junit's jar package is, you can do it like this:

1)Press the Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S  key at the same time
2)select Libraries
3)click +  ,select java
4)select your jar file

#### Method 2:

If you use maven that is easy .
Just in the "pom.xml" file join like that :

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

[image]

[image]